# SurfaceView and Game thread synchronization

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview

I have a SurfaceView and a GameThread which updates game state and draw a bitmap on canvas. surface.update() below updates game variables outside the lock and creates a bitmap that has to be drawn on canvas. After locking  surface.doDraw draws that bitmap on canvas. Update() is outside UI thread locking is to improve performance. Is this approach wrong? Do I have to update under the lock?

```
public class GameThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private GameViewSurface surface;
private boolean running = false;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder holder, GameViewSurface GameSurface) {
    surfaceHolder = holder;
    surface = GameSurface;
}

public void setRunning(boolean run) {
    running = run;
}

public boolean getRunning() {
    return running;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {

        Canvas canvas=null;
        try {

            if(!surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            surface.update();
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {

                surface.doDraw(canvas);
            }
        } catch(Exception p){


        }finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                try {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `surface.update() below ...creates a bitmap that has to be drawn on canvas.` can you do this before you invalidate the canvas?

Comment: I am sorry I did not get you. I dont think I Invalidate the canvas anywhere. doDraw calls canvas.save() , drawBitmap and restore(). Which line are you talking about? Thanks